# Trying to compile for iOS - Visual Studio for Mac - iPad Pro 12.9 inch (2017) and selecting correct simulator to test with

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, visual-studio-mac

This is the list of simulators I have available at the moment in Visual Studio for Mac:

[image]

What changes do I need to make so that I can see **iPad Pro 12.9” (2017)** in the list?

I see a similar device listed but it says **4th generation**. When I look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Pro_(2nd_generation)) it refers to it as a **2nd generation**. this older one is the device my colleague has (in another country). Am I am to use this choice to simulate his device? Will my current build configuration support his device?

Comment: The simulators VS Mac displays depends on what Xcode has installed. Does this other stackoverflow link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524085/device-ipad-pro-12-9-inch-2nd-generation-not-in-list-of-available-simulato

Comment: @MattWard Thanks. I will have a look.